# Take picture automatically with MediaStore Intent

Tags: java, android, camera, widget, android-camera

What I am looking to do is to capture an image on a button click, without requesting any other input from the user.

At the moment I'm using a `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent inside my activity, which is called when pressing a button on a widget. At the moment this opens the camera preview allowing me to take a picture.

That's all working great, however what I'm looking to do is when the user presses the button on the widget, take the picture straight away and display a preview of the captured image. So it essentially snaps the picture automatically, without the need for the user to press anything else.

I tried using the Camera API directly, using a `SurfaceView` class to capture the image and call the `PictureCallback` etc, this worked how I want it to, however the quality of the images was very low and I couldn't figure out how to change it.

So I guess I'm looking for an answer to either of those two problems, or both if anyone knows them.

Firstly, is there anyway, using something similar to a `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent to snap the image automatically without requesting the user to take the picture.

Or secondly, how can I increase the quality and resolution of an image captured using the Camera API directly (`camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback`); and all that business).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [autoFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus%28android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback%29)?

Comment: Do you mean to make the quality better?

Comment: Yes. autoFocus() will start the camera and you can call takePicture in the callback.

Comment: I just added that, it definitely makes the image clearer so thanks for that, but the resolution is still very low, any ideas?

Comment: I think its controlled by a setting. It doesn't show up in Camera.Parameters [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html]. Try looking at the source of Camera app. May be you'll find an undocumented parameter.

Comment: Ahh what a fool, myself I mean. I tried messing with params.setPictureSize() but I didn't think it worked. I just looked at some of my cameras good images, resolution was at 3264 x 2448, so I just entered those values in as the parameters in setPictureSize(). Now it seems the images saved are nicely focussed and high resolution. I think thats the one :D Thanks very much Rohit.